# How to copy contents of 1 pytest.mark contents to another

Tags: python, pytest

I want to copy contents of one marker to another marker .

For eg :
I have a marker , pytest.mark.mini, this marker have some tests . Now I have created another marker called pytest.mark.integration, this marker will have "mini" and some more tests .

I want to copy mini marker contents to integration marker . How can I do this copying .

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add markers dynamically, for example in the [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook. Place the code below in a `conftest.py` in the project dir:

```
import pytest

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        if item.get_closest_marker('mini') and not item.get_closest_marker('integration'):
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.integration)
```

and each test marked with `@pytest.mark.mini` will be also marked with `@pytest.mark.integration`.